# PFC8574 4x4 keypad: correct wiring?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I bought a few PFC8574 and 4x4 keypads for a small project. I'm unclear on the correct wiring of the keypad to the PFC8574.

On the [Arduino Playground's site](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2CPortExpanderAndKeypads), there are pull-up resistors for each column, but on a few other sites (like [this one](http://majsterkowo.pl/klawiatura-numeryczna-pod-i2c/) that I can't read, but I understand a schematic and there's a third example too, but I don't have the reputation to post it), the wiring does straight into the IC.

Does it depend on the library that's being used?  Or what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok look at this image:
[image]

I'm not sure how your keypad is layed out but if you use a probe pin to test your connections via a multimeter, you can mark which ones correspond to the image.

I am ASSUMING you are going to use the code from arduino playground.

This is the format:

Pins of keypad (**IN THE IMAGE**) - Pins of PFC8547

Here are the pin connections:

1 - nothing

2 - 9

3 - 4

4 - 6

5 - 7

6 - 10

7 - 11

8 - 5

Also include the pull-up resistors.
Your ABCD keys will be ignored

(This is like wiring a bomb...)